# Fetch sidebar links for static pages

Tags: next.js

So I have a bunch of pages. Each page has its own set of links for the sidebar. On page change, I would like the old sidebar links from the previous page to animate off screen and the new ones to show. Since all of these pages are statically generated, how would I do this? I assume using one giant local json with all the links is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create component you another file, then import as `Lazy`. it gonna have its own chunk file.

From [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)

```
const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/hello'))
```